# Testing Angular http interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I need to make my application log a user in with saved credentials and retry a request on a 401 and I'm having a hard time testing it because I need the initial call to return a 401, but then return a 200 after the login request happens again.

Here is my test so far:

```
it("should call login if the status is 401", function() {
  $httpBackend.whenGET(api.baseUrl + "/auth/login").respond(200);
  $httpBackend.whenGET(api.baseUrl + "/practice/active").respond(401);

  api.practiceActiveInquery(function(result) {
    expect(login.fn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  $httpBackend.flush();

});
```

The problem is I need the whenGET of /practice/active to respond with a 200 after it's called once with the 401, or I get caught in a circle. Or am I thinking about how to test an http interceptor completely wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you want to use `expectGET` instead of `whenGET`. `expectGET` only fulfills one request at a time, so you can change the response each time a request is made. Something like this:

```
it("should call login if the status is 401", function() {
  $httpBackend.whenGET(api.baseUrl + "/auth/login").respond(200);
  $httpBackend.expectGET(api.baseUrl + "/practice/active").respond(401); //will return 401 the 1st time
  $httpBackend.expectGET(api.baseUrl + "/practice/active").respond(200); //will return 200 the 2nd time

  api.practiceActiveInquery(function(result) {
    expect(login.fn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  $httpBackend.flush();

});
```